# Change nginx root on different requests

Tags: php, nginx, root

I am trying to configure nginx. If I enter `http://localhost/dav` it should use `index.php` script from configured `root` (c:/wt-nmp/www/app-dav/frontend/web) in `location /dav` directive. But when I debug nginx it still uses `root` configured in `server` config.

In debug it looks like:

1. It uses `location /dav` and sets `root` to new value and changes to `index.php?dav`
2. Now it uses `location ~ \.php$` but `$document_root` still points to `c:/wt-nmp/www/m24/web`, but I think it should be changed in `location /dav` as mentioned in point 1.

My problem is how to configure nginx to use script from `c:/wt-nmp/www/app-dav/frontend/web` when I enter `http://localhost/dav`.

I think this code should work like that:

1. `root` is set from `server` directive to `.../m24/web`
2. When I enter url `http://example.com/dav` then directive `location /dav` should change the `root` to `.../m24/app-dav/frontend/web` and php script from that location should be executed.
3. But when I debug this app, script from `.../m24/web` is still executed. Why `root` directive in `location /dav` doesn't change `$document_root` value. `$document_root` still is pointing to `.../m24/web`.

Most important part of my config looks like:

```
server {
    ...

    root "c:/wt-nmp/www/m24/web";
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location /dav {
        root "c:/wt-nmp/www/m24/app-dav/frontend/web";
        # The $uri gets mangled by nginx, however Yii urlmanager requires REQUEST_URI to route
        set $original_uri $uri?$args;
        # Try the actual uri, then uri as a directory, then send it to yii
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location / {
        #set original_uri to use as the request_uri later on  
        #The $uri gets mangled by nginx, however Yii urlmanager requires REQUEST_URI to route  
        set $original_uri $uri?$args;
        #Try the actual uri, then uri as a directory, then send it to yii  
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass                  php_farm;
        include                       nginx.fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI     $original_uri; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You may get a better response for this over at [server fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Done. Should I delete this question?

Comment: IMO its not actually off-topic for this site, just think more people will be able to answer on SF.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 location directives, one for php files under `/dav` and another for static files under `/dav` :

```
location ~ ^/dav/.*\.php$ {                 
        root "c:/wt-nmp/www/app-dav/frontend";
        try_files $uri =404; 
        include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
}

location ~ ^/dav/ {
         root "c:/wt-nmp/www/app-dav/frontend";
}
```

This way files will be served from `c:/wt-nmp/www/app-dav/frontend/dav`. So you might also want to `rename c:/wt-nmp/www/app-dav/frontend/web c:/wt-nmp/www/app-dav/frontend/dav` because the URL path must match the root subdirectory!

Also, make sure you use the latest version of [WT-NMP - portable Nginx Mysql Php development stack for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wtnmp) `

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't think this will solve my problem. I edited my post to give you more information what I try to achieve.